# Minimizing distance between an ellipse and a point

Tags: calculus, optimization, quadratics, conic-sections

**Problem**

An ellipse has the formula:

$$\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$$

What is the shortest distance from the ellipse to the point $P = (a,0)?$

**Attempted solution:**

I have previously solved the same problem with P = (1,0) and P = (2,0). For P = (1,0), the minimum where x = 1.8 and y = 1.6 and a distance of $\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5}$.

For P = (2,0), the local minimum was larger than the distance between P and the ellipse at y = 0., which was equal to 1. So there is some threshold for $a$ for which the local minimum is not truly the smallest distance.

Basic strategy:

1) Solve the ellipse formula for y and put that into the distance formula for the distance between the ellipse and the point (Pythagorean theorem).

2) Take the derivative.

3) Set the derivative to 0 and solve for x.

4) Use the ellipse formula to solve for y.

5) Put in x and y in the distance formula and get the distance.

However, at some threshold the distance between the point and the ellipse where y = 0 is even shorter. So the shortest distance will have one of two cases, one between 0 and just below the threshold and one for the threshold value and above.

I figured that I could apply the same method I did for the previous cases of P = (1,0) and P = (2,0) and see if I can find some way to find this threshold.

**Use the ellipse formula and solve for y:**

$$\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1 \Rightarrow y = \sqrt{4\Big(1-\frac{x^2}{9}\Big)}$$

**Write down distance formula**

$$D = \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + y^2}$$

**Put in y from the ellipse formula**

$$D = \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + \Big(\sqrt{4\Big(1-\frac{x^2}{9}\Big)}\Big)^2}$$

**Simplify:**

$$D = \sqrt{\frac{5}{9} \cdot x^2 - 2ax +4}$$

**Take the derivative:**

$$D' = \frac{\frac{10}{9}x-2a}{2\sqrt{\frac{5}{9}x^2 - 2ax +4}}$$

**Set the derivative to zero and solve for x:**

$$\frac{10}{18}x -a =  0 \Rightarrow x = 1.8a$$

**Use ellipse function and solve for y:**

$$y = \sqrt{4\Big(1-\frac{(1.8a)^2}{9}\Big)} = a\sqrt{0.76}$$

**Putting in x and y to the distance formula**

$$D = \sqrt{(1.8a-a)^2 + (a\sqrt{0.76})^2} = \sqrt{0.64a^2 + 0.76a^2} = \sqrt{1.4a^2} = a\sqrt{1.4}$$

...but I feel like I am not getting anywhere. This is not the correct distance and the threshold is nowhere to be seen.

Expected answer is:

$$\sqrt{4-\frac{4}{5}a^2}$$

for $0 < a < \frac{5}{3}$ and

$$|a-3|$$

if $a \geq \frac{5}{3}$

Comment: $a^2$ is missing in step (simplifiy)

Comment: calculation mistake while finding $y$ check it again.

Comment: It is **much** easier to minimize $D^2,$ which is the same as minimizing $D$ since both are positive.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to remember $-3\leq x\leq 3.$

It is much easier, without even using calculus, to minimize $D^2$ than the minimize $D.$

We have that the distance $D$ satisfying:

$$\begin{align}D^2&=(x-a)^2+y^2\\
&=x^2-2ax+a^2+4\left(1-\frac{x^2}{9}\right)\\
&=\frac{5}{9}x^2-2ax+a^2+4\\
&=\frac{5}{9}\left(x-\frac{9}{5}a\right)^2-\frac{9}{5}a^2+a^2+4\tag{1}
\\
&=\frac{5}{9}\left(x-\frac{9}{5}a\right)^2+4-\frac{4a^2}{5}
\end{align}$$

the line (1) by completing the square.

We want the minimum value of $D^2$ for $x\in[-3,3].$

Now, the right side is is minimized when $x=\frac{9}{5}a,$ but $\frac{9}{5}a\in[-3,3]$ if and only if $|a|\leq \frac{5}{3}.$

If $|a|>\frac{5}{3}$ then minimum is when $x=\pm 3$, and $y=0$ so the minimum $D=|3-|a||.$

Otherwise, if $|a|\leq \frac{5}{3},$ then $x=\frac{9}{5}a$ gives the minimum $D^2=4-\frac{4a^2}{5}$ or $$D=2\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{5}}$$

---

**Another approach**

If $(x,y)$ is a local minimum-maximum distance point to $(a,0)$ then the tangent angle the curve must be perpendicular to $(x-a,y).$

But the tangent at $(x,y)$ is $(x',y')=(9y,-4x).$ So:

$$0=(x',y')\cdot (x-a,y)=9y(x-a)-4xy = y(5x-9a)$$

So either $y=0,$ then $x=\pm 3.$ Or $5x-9a=0.$ But that is only possible if $\frac{9a}{5}\in[-3,3].$

The maximum $D$ is given when $x=\pm 3$ with the opposite sign of $a.$

The rest is the same. If $\frac{9}{5}a\in[-3,3],$ you get $x=\frac{9}{5}a$ yields the minimum, otherwise $x=\operatorname{sgn}(a)\cdot 3$ yields the minimum.

---

More generally, if we use the curve $x^2+Cy^2=B^2$ for any $B,C$, $B>0,$ then the potential points nearest to $(a,0)$ when $y=0,x=\pm B$ and when $(C-1)x-Ca=0.$

(In your case, $B=2,C=\frac{9}{4}.)$

If $C=1,$ you have a circle, and if $a\neq 0,$ you get $(\pm B,0)$ as your potential points. If $C=1,a=0,$ then $(a,0)$ is the center of the circle and the distance is constant for all $(x,y)$ on the circle.

If $C=0$ then your "curve" is $x\pm B,$ and we get $(C-1)x-Ca=0$ when $x=0,$ which is not in the valid domain for $x.$

If $C\neq 0,1,$ you get the additional (optional) case $x=\frac{C}{C-1}a.$

If $0<C<1,$ the case $x=\frac{C}{C-1}a$ is the opposite sign of $a,$ so $(x,y)$ is further from $(a,0)$ than $(-x,y),$ so that cases in not a minimum. [This case is one of an ellipse oblong in the $y$ direction, so this value is a local maximum.

If $C<0,$ then we include the optional case when $|a|\geq B\frac{C-1}{C}.$

If $C>1$, you include the optional case when $|a|\leq B\frac{C-1}{C}.$

---

For example, if $B=1,C=-1,$ then the closest point to $(a,0)$ in $x^2-y^2=1$ has distance:

$$D=\begin{cases}||a|-1|&|a|\leq 2\\ \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2a^2-4}&|a|>2\end{cases}$$ 
When $|a|>2,$ you have $x=\frac{a}{2},y=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2-4}.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write $$d=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2}$$ where $$y^2=4-\frac{4}{9}x^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x-a)^2+y^2=k^2,$ where $k\geq0.$

Thus, the equation $$(x-a)^2+4\left(1-\frac{x^2}{9}\right)=k^2$$ has real roots.

We have
$$\frac{5}{9}x^2-2ax+a^2+4-k^2=0,$$ which gives
$$a^2-\frac{5}{9}(a^2+4-k^2)\geq0$$
and $$k\geq2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{5}a^2},$$ as your result.

Comment: That doesn't work in general, because we are restricted to $x\in[-3,3],$ which is to say when $y^2\geq 0.$

Comment: In particular, when $|a|\geq 3$ you have the smallest distance is $x=\pm 3$ and thus $||a|-3|$ is the minimum. In your czse, the minimum is always $\leq 2.$

Comment: Yes, I know, @Thomas. There is more work.

Comment: But there is nothing in your answer that indicates that this is incomplete, and, in fact, you end your answer with "and <wrong answer> is your answer."

Comment: @Thomas Andrews It was a hint only. I said to you already that it's not a full solution. I think your down-voting it's just vandalism.

Comment: Comments are not part of the answer - they are temporary things, potentially cleared out at a later date.   The answer gives every indication that it is complete, so the answer is wrong, and, given you know that it is wrong, and you haven't updated it with a note describing it as an incomplete answer or hint, it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be solved with the method of Lagrange multiplier.

$$L = (x-a)^2 + y^2 - \lambda \left(\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} -1\right)$$

$$ 0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 2(x-a) - \frac{2}{9} \lambda x$$

$$ 0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 2y - \frac{1}{2} \lambda y \phantom{00000}$$

From the second equation, $\lambda=4$ or $y=0$.

When $|a|\ge \frac{5}{3}$, we have $y=0$ and the distance is $||a|-3|$. [Please see the discussion in the comments below.]

Otherwise, $\lambda=4$, which implies $x=\frac{9}{5}a$, so the distance squared is

$$\delta^2 = (x-a)^2+y^2 = \frac{16 a^2}{25} + 4\left( 1-\frac{9a^2}{25}\right)=4-\frac{4}{5} a^2$$

$$\delta = 2\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{5}}.$$

Comment: $x=\frac{9}{5}a$ only works if $x=\frac{9}{5}a\in[-3,3].$ That is a far smaller range than $a\in(-3,3).$

Comment: Right, I agree with you.  Comparing $|a|$ to 3 is a mistake.  For example $a=2$ takes us past the ellipse to $x=\frac{9}{5} \cdot 2 = \frac{18}{5}>3$.  So I think that should read $\frac{9}{5} |a| \ge 3$ or $|a|>\frac{5}{3}$.  I'll correct that above.  Thank you very much!